# Karate - Referencing variable within schema, js function

Tags: karate

I have .js file whose content is as below... where `companyAssociations` is list of object for which i have defined schema on top in var...

```
function() {

    var companyAssociationsSchema = '{"companyId":"#string", "displayName":"#string", "associationType":"#string", "companyType":"#string" }';

 return {
   "StationSchema":{
      "stationId":"#string",
      "companyAssociations":"#[] "+ companyAssociationsSchema,
      "primaryBroadcastLanguage":"#string"
   }
 }
}
```

and here is how i read/load schema in my feature file `* def getStationResponse = call read(path to above file)` and than wherever i need to check for above schema i refer to it as `getStationResponse.StationSchema`
above works in karate 0.9.6 but i am having hard time getting same thing working in karate 1.1.0

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand anything here, so please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas thank you for your response... i have tried updating my post in hope to make more sense out of it... if its still not clear let me know and i can surely submit an issue

Comment: please read the instructions. it is not about submitting an issue. it is for others to replicate the problem. what you have posted is useless (at least to me). also if you follow the instructions, you are most likely to find out what you are doing wrong. is it so hard to submit a simple example that others can cut and paste and try ?